# SVN can't update source code file from the repository

Tags: svn, assembla

I have a really old source code file in an Assembla hosted subversion repository. This file is updated frequently and we never had any problems with it.

However, now, when I update this file, instead of the latest version (which I can see when browsing the repository, so it is on the server), I receive an older version of the file. When I try to update the file to a specific revision (such as HEAD), I receive the following subversion message:

```
svn: E204900: /home/fibo/trabalho/tempSorteie/SorteieFB/grails-app/domain/promocoes/Promocao.groovy was not properly updated; may be it is already removed from the repository along with its parent.
```

When I try to show the file history, I receive the following message

```
Problems while loading file history: svn: E195012: Unable to find repository location for '/home/fibo/trabalho/tempSorteie/SorteieFB/grails-app/domain/promocoes/Promocao.groovy@UNDEFINED' in revision '1,216'
```

I tried to just remove the file (and merge my changes after that), but the file is restored with the older version, not the newer one.

Have anybody ever seen such an behavior?

Comment: Have you tried updating your entire working copy instead of just that one file? That's the normal method of working in SVN.

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me. Try doing a cleanup of your whole repository before updating again. And check your 'Changes' tab at the bottom.